# We sometimes refer to ETH as `0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` on Ethereum, what's the equivalence of BNB on BSC?

Tags: addresses, bsc

I see lots of contracts refer to ETH as `0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` on Ethereum, since there's not a token contract for ETH itself. So I wonder if the equivalence on BNB Smart Chain, BNB coin, has a similar representation?

Answer (score 1):

Contracts can create whatever internal aliases for Ether. There is no standard for that. And it doesn't really matter which one a contract uses, as long as it uses it consistently (also with its frontends).

So any chain and any project can use whatever 'names' for their native asset, if it makes their contract easier to write and/or understand.

Honestly though, I've never seen that alias for Ether. Most projects I look at, they either use WETH or then don't pretend that it's a token - it has to be treated differently anyway.

Comment: I understand there is no standard for that but there must be a convention for it. I saw a lot of cases where ETH is represented as 0xee...ee, so I presume there's an equivalence on BSC.